# Aquamacs 2.4: how to input "@" in commands for outline mode?

Tags: emacs, aquamacs

I'm using Aquamacs 2.4 on MacOS X 10.6.8.

For `AUCTeX` I want to use a command like `C-c @ C-n` for navigation in outline-mode (see http://devcheatsheet.com/static/pdf/auctex-ref.pdf).

However, I don't see how I can enter the "@" sign. If I try to do it (on my Mac keyboard that would be `Alt-L`), I get the error message "alt-L is undefined".

In fact, also in the Text I can not enter the @ sign, it then says  "keyboard macro terminated by a command ringing the bell".

I'm using the Keyboard settings:

- Meta & German
- Right Option is Meta